# Is there a way for a SKILL script to find and replace parts on schematic?

Tags: cadence

I am trying to write a SKILL script that replaces parts on a schematic given a csv file with the original part, and the desired replacement. So far I have looked through the [Intro to Skill Programming](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/sites.gatech.edu/dist/0/367/files/2016/03/Intro_to_skill_prog.pdf). I only see information about file I/O and nothing, to my knowledge, that would allow the script to find and replace parts in the schematic.

Comment: I'd recommend using https://support.cadence.com for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register on the Cadence support site https://support.cadence.com/
There is a lot of information and examples on the site.
Below is just an example of how to find and update instances in schematic

```
procedure(ATUpdateSchematicInstances(libName cellName viewName updateTable @optional (ignoreErrors nil))
        let( (cvId instList instOldLib instOldCell key destLibName destCellName vicViewList instOldView updateResult errorInstList)
            
            cvId=dbOpenCellViewByType(libName cellName viewName "schematic" "a")
            instList=cvId~>instHeaders
            foreach(inst instList
                instOldLib=inst->libName
                instOldCell=inst->cellName
                instOldView=inst->viewName
    
                key=ATCreateCellInfo(instOldLib instOldCell)
    
                when(updateTable[key]
                    destLibName=updateTable[key]->libName
                    destCellName=updateTable[key]->cellName
                    
                    updateResult=dbSetInstHeaderMasterName(inst destLibName destCellName instOldView)
                );when
            );foreach
            
            schCheck(cvId)
            dbSave(cvId)
            dbClose(cvId)
        );let

);procedure ATUpdateSchematicInstances
```